# Is it possible to remove the fd link in /proc/<pid>/fd?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I've been trying to setup an kernel module to later fake a GPS within a program, in order to simulate communication with gpsd which uses a fixed path. But right now I'm stuck due to gpsd checking if there's more than one link to the file in /proc//fd before starting reading/writing.

Is there a way to exclude the link from this directory but still be able to read/write to file from my gpsfake? Or bypass this fd tracking altogether from the module?

Comment: I have not tried it but what happens if you mount a union filesystem (I forget which ones are current in-kernel) over top of /proc and then delete the fd link from the upper layer? As I recall it, the union fs will create a white-out file to make it appear deleted even though it is still really there.

Comment: I have not heard about union filesystems until now, I'm pretty new to these kernel stuff. Guess I'll get some reading going.

Comment: Try bind mounting something else over that `/proc/<pid>/fd/` directory where that link is found; as root: `mkdir empty; mount -B empty /proc/PID/fd`.

Comment: Hey @mosvy. Your suggestion worked so far. If I initialize my fakegps and do the bind mount, it goes through the gpsd check, while still reading apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/proc/<pid>/` is a *filesystem-like* view on the process `<pid>`, exposed by the kernel.

As such, the **only** way to remove/add/change anything within this directory is by changing the process itself (in your case: make the process close the offending file-descriptor to have the corresponding symlink go away).

The *other* way is to patch the kernel, but you probably don't want to do this.

Comment: I guess closing the file descriptor is not really possibility for what I was trying now, but yeah... I'll see if I can get more leeway later with this problem. Thanks! =)